# Калькулятор услуг, умножение на количество

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

На одной странице сайта есть 3 вкладок, для каждой вкладки(проводной, беспроводной, уже есть оборудование) есть свой калькулятор, как можно будет сделать функционал увеличения кол-ва чтобы оно умножалось на стоимость и абонплату, и выводился с правой стороны самого калькулятора. Ниже приведен код реализации калькулятора.  [image: это скрин как выглядит]
[image: это как должно работать увеличение кол-ва]

```js
function openService(serviceName, sum, sum2) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab_service");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(serviceName).style.display = "block";

  $('#' + serviceName + ' .js-subscription-price-summ').text(sum);
  $('#' + serviceName + ' .js-connection-price-summ').text(sum2);
}
$("button.service_menu_link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("button.service_menu_link").removeClass('activetabs2');
  $(this).addClass('activetabs2');
})
$(function() {
  var $tabs = $('.js-list-item > li');
  var timerId = setTimeout(() => changeTab(1), 5000);

  function changeTab(index) {
    $tabs.removeClass('active').eq(index).addClass('active');

    $('.how_works').css('background-image', 'url(' + $tabs.eq(index).data('img') + ')');

    $('.how_work_txt').text($tabs.eq(index).data('content'));

    index = ++index % $tabs.length;

    clearTimeout(timerId);

    timerId = setTimeout(() => changeTab(index), 5000);
  }

  $tabs.each(function(index) {

    $(this).on('click', () => changeTab(index));
  });
});
<!-- Для калькулятора -->
$('.left_tab .onoffswitch-checkbox').on('click', function() {
  checked = $(this).prop('checked');

  block_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  allPrice = $('#' + block_id + ' .js-subscription-price-summ').text();
  allPrice2 = $('#' + block_id + ' .js-connection-price-summ').text();
  allPrice = parseInt(allPrice.replace(/\s/g, ''));
  allPrice2 = parseInt(allPrice2.replace(/\s/g, ''));

  modifyPrice = parseInt($(this).attr('data-price').replace(/\s/g, ''));
  modifyPrice2 = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.col-connection-cost').attr('data-price').replace(/\s/g, ''));

  if (checked) {
    sum = allPrice + modifyPrice;
    sum2 = allPrice2 + modifyPrice2;
  } else {
    sum = allPrice - modifyPrice;
    sum2 = allPrice2 - modifyPrice2;
  }

  $('.js-subscription-price-summ').text(sum);
  $('.js-connection-price-summ').text(sum2);
});
$('.onoffswitch-checkbox').on('click', function() {
  var div = $(this).closest('.product-option');
  $(this).is(":checked") ? div.addClass("red_element") : div.removeClass("red_element");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section class="py-4 review main_services_page">
    <div class="container service_tab_block">
      <div class="container mx-auto tab_menu_title">
        <button class="service_menu_link activetabs2" onclick="openService('with_cable', 4000, 10000)"><span>Проводной комплект</span></button>
        <button class="service_menu_link" onclick="openService('without_cable', 4000, 15000)"><span>Беспроводной комплект</span></button>
        <button class="service_menu_link" onclick="openService('has_equipment', 4000, 0)"><span>Уже есть оборудование</span></button>
      </div>
      <div id="with_cable" class="tab_service">
        <div class="mx-auto other_service_txt">
          <section class="ру-16 table_block">
            <div class="container mx-auto tabb">
              <!----left tab for mobile version---------->
              <div class="left_tab_mobile">
                <h3>Дополнительное оборудование</h3>
              </div>
              <!-----end of LEFT TAB for mobile version---->
              <div class="left_tab">
                <div class="tab_menu_tit">
                  <div>Дополнительное оборудование и услуги</div>
                  <div>Стоимость оборудования</div>
                  <div>Абонентская плата</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option fline">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">Внутренняя сирена</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="2500">2500&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-price="0" data-id="with_cable" id="wired_option_6907" name="wired_option_6907" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6907"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">Онлайн контроль</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="0">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input data-price="0" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-id="with_cable" id="wired_option_6908" name="wired_option_6908" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6908"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">SMS уведомления</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="0">Бесплатно</div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">500&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input data-price="500" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-id="with_cable" id="wired_option_6909" name="wired_option_6909" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6909"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="right_tab">
                <div class="right_tab_info">
                  <div class="title">Общая стоимость</div>
                  <div class="price">
                    <div class="price-title">Подключение</div>
                    <div class="price-value"><strong class="connection-price-summ js-connection-price-summ">10 000</strong> <span class="rub">тг</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price">
                    <div class="price-title">Абон. плата</div>
                    <div class="price-value">
                      <strong class="js-subscription-price-summ">4 000</strong>
                      <span class="rub">тг</span>/мес
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-red-light call-modal-show" onclick="PriceFunction()">Оставить заявку</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="without_cable" class="tab_service" style="display:none;">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <section class="ру-16 table_block">
            <div class="container mx-auto tabb">
              <!----left tab for mobile version---------->
              <div class="left_tab_mobile">
                <h3>Дополнительное оборудование</h3>
              </div>
              <!-----end of LEFT TAB for mobile version---->
              <div class="left_tab second_left">
                <div class="tab_menu_tit">
                  <div>Дополнительное оборудование и услуги</div>
                  <div>Стоимость оборудования</div>
                  <div>Абонентская плата</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option fline">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">Внутренняя сирена</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="2500">2500&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-price="0" id="wired_option_6910" data-id="without_cable" name="wired_option_6910" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6910"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">Онлайн контроль</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="0">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input data-price="0" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-id="without_cable" id="wired_option_6911" name="wired_option_6911" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6911"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">SMS уведомления</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="0">Бесплатно</div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">500&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input data-price="500" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-id="without_cable" id="wired_option_6912" name="wired_option_6912" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6912"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="right_tab">
                <div class="right_tab_info">
                  <div class="title">Общая стоимость</div>
                  <div class="price">
                    <div class="price-title">Подключение</div>
                    <div class="price-value"><strong class="connection-price-summ js-connection-price-summ">10 000</strong> <span class="rub">тг</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price">
                    <div class="price-title">Абон. плата</div>
                    <div class="price-value">
                      <strong class="js-subscription-price-summ">4 000</strong>
                      <span class="rub">тг</span>/мес
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-red-light call-modal-show" onclick="PriceFunction()">Оставить заявку</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="has_equipment" class="tab_service" style="display:none">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <section class="about_bg_services">
            <div class="about_bg"><img src="{{ asset('build/img/about_bg.png') }}" alt=""></div>
          </section>
          <section class="ру-16 table_block">
            <div class="container mx-auto tabb">
              <!----left tab for mobile version---------->
              <div class="left_tab_mobile">
                <h3>Дополнительное оборудование</h3>
              </div>
              <!-----end of LEFT TAB for mobile version---->
              <div class="left_tab">
                <div class="tab_menu_tit">
                  <div>Дополнительное оборудование и услуги</div>
                  <div>Стоимость оборудования</div>
                  <div>Абонентская плата</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option fline">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">Тревожная кнопка</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="2000">2000&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-price="0" id="wired_option_6913" data-id="has_equipment" name="wired_option_6913" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6913"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">Переносная тревожная кнопка</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="10000">10000&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input data-price="0" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="wired_option_6914" data-id="has_equipment" name="wired_option_6914" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6914"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">Внутренняя сирена</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="2500">2500&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input data-price="0" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="wired_option_6915" data-id="has_equipment" name="wired_option_6915" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6915"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-option js-product-option">
                  <div class="col-name">
                    <div class="icon icon-service"></div>
                    <div class="col-name-inner">Онлайн контроль</div>
                    <div class="product-option-help" data-image="/media/devices/service.png" title=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-connection-cost js-col-connection-cost" data-price="0">Бесплатно</div>
                  <div class="col-subscription-cost js-col-subscription-cost">0&nbsp;
                    <div class="rub">тг/месяц</div>
                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                      <input data-price="0" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-id="has_equipment" id="wired_option_6916" name="wired_option_6916" type="checkbox">
                      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="wired_option_6916"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="right_tab">
                <div class="right_tab_info">
                  <div class="title">Общая стоимость</div>
                  <div class="price">
                    <div class="price-title">Подключение</div>
                    <div class="price-value"><strong class="connection-price-summ js-connection-price-summ">10 000</strong> <span class="rub">тг</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price">
                    <div class="price-title">Абон. плата</div>
                    <div class="price-value">
                      <strong class="js-subscription-price-summ">4 000</strong>
                      <span class="rub">тг</span>/мес
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-red-light call-modal-show" onclick="PriceFunction()">Оставить заявку</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: пример не работает

Comment: @Алексей теперь работает